# How to write (10) in excel using jsp

Tags: excel, jsp, numbers

I am doing some stuff with Excel with JSP.

Question is :

How to write excel that will print "(10)" in excel sheet.
If you write (10) in excel it will convert to -10.
I don't want to convert value to -10.

Make sure i am not using any API for writing in excel i just simply change the header type to excel. and using tab i am writing or responding with excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either precede it with a ' (as in `'(10)` or change the formatting of the cells to `text` *before* setting the value

Comment: i am not using any api like apache poi can you tell me how can i change the type of cell just using jsp with set content type to  response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");